# Converting the Nested Json format/ file into Flat files using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing one of the problem here. I have data set which is nested

```
 {
    "members": [
      {
        "firstname": "John", 
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "orgname": "Anon",
        "phone": "916-555-1234",
        "mobile": "",
      },
      {
        "firstname": "Jane",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "orgname": "Anon",
        "phone": "916-555-4321",
        "mobile": "916-555-7890",
      },
    "teamname": "1",
    "team_size": "5",
    "team_status": "low"
    }
```

and another one which is not nested

```
{
"members": [
  {
    "firstname": "John", 
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "orgname": "Anon",
    "phone": "916-555-1234",
    "mobile": "",
  },
"teamname": "1",
"team_size": "5",
"team_status": "low"
}
```

I have handled the nested one through the code

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(json_file2), orient='columns')

## print(df2)

## df3 = pd.concat([json_normalize(x) for x in df2['members'].values.tolist()], keys= df2.index)

## df3 = df2.drop('members', 1).join(df3.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)).reset_index(drop=True)

I am getting the error saying "saying “TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable”"

Can you please help  me out with the issue.

```
{
"teams": [
{

"members": [
  {
    "firstname": "John", 
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "orgname": "Anon",
    "phone": "916-555-1234",
    "mobile": "",
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Jane",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "orgname": "Anon",
    "phone": "916-555-4321",
    "mobile": "916-555-7890",
  },
"teamname": "1",
"team_size": "5",
"team_status": "low"
},
{

"members": [
  {
    "firstname": "Mickey",
    "lastname": "Moose",
    "orgname": "Moosers",
    "phone": "916-555-0000",
    "mobile": "916-555-1111",
  },
"teamname": "2",
"team_size": "5",
"team_status": "low"
]
}       
]

}
```

Comment: Is difference between jsons? Also jsons are not valid, so added `]` in my answer before `teamname`.

Comment: I test last json by https://jsonlint.com/, but invalid, it seems some `]` missing too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me working:

```
d1 = {
    "members": [
      {
        "firstname": "John", 
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "orgname": "Anon",
        "phone": "916-555-1234",
        "mobile": "",
      },
      {
        "firstname": "Jane",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "orgname": "Anon",
        "phone": "916-555-4321",
        "mobile": "916-555-7890",
      }],
    "teamname": "1",
    "team_size": "5",
    "team_status": "low"
    }

d2 = {
"members": [
  {
    "firstname": "John", 
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "orgname": "Anon",
    "phone": "916-555-1234",
    "mobile": "",
  }],
"teamname": "1",
"team_size": "5",
"team_status": "low"
}
```

---

```
df1 = json_normalize(d1, 'members', ['team_size', 'team_status','teamname'])
print (df1)
  firstname lastname        mobile orgname         phone team_size teamname  \
0      John      Doe                  Anon  916-555-1234         5        1   
1      Jane      Doe  916-555-7890    Anon  916-555-4321         5        1   

  team_status  
0         low  
1         low  

df2 = json_normalize(d2, 'members', ['team_size', 'team_status','teamname'])
print (df2)
  firstname lastname mobile orgname         phone team_size teamname  \
0      John      Doe           Anon  916-555-1234         5        1   

  team_status  
0         low
```

Comment: It should be one single frame as the json file is one single file and we cannot extract these files as a seperate ones.

Comment: @Ishan - OK, can you change last json for valid json?

Comment: @Ishan - Check last commnet under question.

Comment: Hi Jezrael, I feel you are right. The Json file that i am receiving right now is not of the right format. Thank you for your support. let me check with the source first.

Comment: Hey Hi , I just found out that it has one element then it is treat as an object and if it has multiple element then it is treated as an array. The problem now is that how do I normalise the file because in the same object we have data which belongs to object type and array type .. how shall I normalise that ?